# Elasticsearch mapping different numeric types

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping

Is there a way to ignore mappings in elasticsearch? Im ingesting a json payload that has a numeric key that can be any numerical value. It can be a float or long or a mix... how do I get around these errors?

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"mapper [data.path.witnesses.snr] cannot be changed from type [float] to [long]"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"mapper [data.path.witnesses.snr] cannot be changed from type [float] to [long]"},"status":400}
```

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic.html

Comment: This doesn't actually cover the use case or issue I'm describing. This is specifically about mapping. I am not setting a mapping when creating new indexes. Typically this is ok but for some reason, elasticsearch separates numeric json into multiple types of numerical json that can't all live together. I need a work around to this